# TreeTagger can't find Charsetname when used in Uima Pipeline

Tags: uima, treetagger, text-chunking, dkpro-core

I would like to use the TreeTagger for chunking inside an uima pipeline for a German text. The chunking works fine when I start the Tagger with cmd, but causes the following error when used in the pipeline:

```
    org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
    at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:150)
    at de.fraunhofer.fkie.re_analysis.RA_pipeline.main(RA_pipeline.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:99)
    at org.annolab.tt4j.TreeTaggerWrapper$Reader.<init>(TreeTaggerWrapper.java:946)
    at org.annolab.tt4j.TreeTaggerWrapper.process(TreeTaggerWrapper.java:598)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.treetagger.TreeTaggerChunker.process(TreeTaggerChunker.java:293)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
    ... 8 more
```

I suppose I should specify the parameter "Chunk_Mapping_Location", but I don't know to which file. The chunker is initialised in the following way:

```
                AnalysisEngineDescription chunker =
                    AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(
                                TreeTaggerChunker.class,
                                TreeTaggerChunker.PARAM_EXECUTABLE_PATH, "C:/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger.exe",
                                TreeTaggerChunker.PARAM_MODEL_LOCATION, "C:/TreeTagger/lib/german-chunker-utf8.par",
                                TreeTaggerChunker.PARAM_PERFORMANCE_MODE, true,
                                TreeTaggerChunker.PARAM_PRINT_TAGSET, true,
                                TreeTaggerChunker.PARAM_LANGUAGE, "de"
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like TreeTaggerChunking is missing `PARAM_MODEL_ENCODING` which prevents it being usable with directly specified models. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-core/issues/1267).

You can get around this by packaging the TreeTagger models as JARs using the `build.xml` Ant script included with DKPro Core. The process is described in the [DKPro Core developer documentation](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.9.2/docs/developer-guide.html#_example_how_to_package_treetagger_binaries_and_models).

*Disclosure:* I am one of the DKPro Core developers.